# Website back end C# to execute Powershell against Exchange-Online

Tags: c#, powershell, iis, exchange-server

Is there a Better Exchange interface/API to do forwarding/unforwarding of Mailboxes and Adding/Removing members to a group in a Web Application than using PowerShell?

One of the things that our IT department has to do multiple times a day is forward and unforward emails from Inside sales team members when they are out.

I’m looking for a way for this to be self service, so the user, or the manager can do it.

I’d like to create the C# Code that can accomplish the task that we do against the Exchange-Online server. Create some Functions that your can call and pass in the proper parameters and have myportal do the mail forwarding/unforwarding.

I would create a user that uses a Token/Key/Cert to access the server and have that embedded in an on-Prem DB.

Is using Powershell the Proper way to do this? This is one of many Sample C# snips that uses PowerShell in c# to do the connection and execute the Powershell Exchange-Online commands.
[Using Exchange Online PowerShell with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77009080/using-exchange-online-powershell-with-c-sharp)

Are there any issues with creating this type of code on a IIS Server Web that does the Remote Exchange-Online Connection? What is needed on the Webserver to Facilitate the connection if I can run the same commands in PowerShell on the server itself?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell is without a doubt the most powerful way to interact with Exchange Online. But if you want something more user-friendly, there are two widely used tools, one is the **Microsoft Graph API**, it is an API that allows you to interact with Exchange Online and some other Microsoft services, and the other is **Exchange Web Services (EWS)** , is a discontinued tool but is still a viable option for more specific cases.

Comment: Seems like Microsoft Graph API is the way to go, Looks like I can use it for adding and removing members to a Distribution list with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Though I can not find anything in Microsoft Graph API for Setting DeliverToMailboxAndForward  and ForwardingSMTPAddress. Just setting Mailbox rules for forwarding, which isn't exactly the same.